# test class on scheduled job simply stalls out

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

Sometimes it will run and give the 'this job already exists' or it just hangs for hours until it eventually decides to work...right now it's been hanging for 14 hours in a test environment. Everywhere I've looked online says this is how you handle test classes for these scheduled jobs.

EDIT: Also i know it would probably be a better test if I inserted some user data prior to the Test.startTest()... but that's besides the point. I'm just trying to get this to run and not hang for hours.

test Class:

```
@istest public with sharing class Deactive_User_full_org_TEST {
    public static testMethod void Deactive_User_full_org_TEST() {

       
        Test.startTest();
        string CRON_EXP = '0 0 12 * * ?';
        Deactive_User_full_org schJob = new Deactive_User_full_org(); 
        string jobId = system.schedule('DeactivateInactiveUsers', 
                                        CRON_EXP, schJob);

        test.stoptest();

 
    }
}
```

Class:

```
    public class Deactive_User_full_org implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext Context) {


        User[] legacyUsers = [SELECT Id  
                            FROM User
                            WHERE Is_Active_Standard_User__c  = TRUE
                            AND Department__c = 'LegacyORG'
                            AND Integration_User__c = FALSE
                            AND Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId 
                                            FROM LoginHistory
                                            WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_DAYS:180)];
        
        
        for(User record: legacyUsers){
            record.IsActive = false;
        }
        Database.update(legacyUsers, false);

        User[] newUsers = [SELECT Id  
                            FROM User
                            WHERE Is_Active_Standard_User__c  = TRUE
                            AND Department__c != 'LegacyORG'
                            AND Department__c != NULL
                            AND Department__c != 'None'
                            AND Integration_User__c = FALSE
                            AND Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId 
                                            FROM LoginHistory
                                            WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_DAYS:90)];

        for(User record: newUsers){
            record.IsActive = false;
        }
        Database.update(newUsers, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never heard about a test class waiting "for hours until it eventually decides to work" but I can give you one idea on why you get the "job already exists" error.

The line below will fail if you already have a job scheduled with that name. Therefore, if somebody manually schedules the job with that name you may end up with conflicts

```
string jobId = system.schedule('DeactivateInactiveUsers', CRON_EXP, schJob);
```

One way to avoid the issue is to randomly append a number to the job name. You can do this in the test class like so

```
String suffix = ' - ' + String.valueOf((Math.random() * 100));
string jobId = system.schedule('DeactivateInactiveUsers'+suffix, CRON_EXP, schJob);
```

Then it's very unlikely two jobs will have the same name and you'll avoid that particular conflict.

Comment: So I did as you suggested, it still pops up with the 'test taking a long time' prompt whenever I'm running this test class. Is there anyway to speed this up? It's not a complex bit of code that's getting tested, and there's the fact i'm not making test data so that itself should speed things up.

Comment: is it because my string CRON_EXP = '0 0 12 * * ?'; is set at that value? I'm just looking to make the test class executive instantly....and not take forever.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to avoid this problem altogether by **not** unit testing the Schedulable implementation via `System.schedule` - after all, you don't need to check that Salesforce correctly invokes your Schedulable implementation but rather that your code functions correctly.

This is most easily done if your Schedulable doesn't use the SchedulableContext itself (which appears to be true in your case). However, it's still possible to handle this for most purposes by fabricating a fake context using a custom implementation of this interface.

In your case I would change the test to:

```
@IsTest
private class Deactive_User_full_org_TEST {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehaviour() {
        Deactive_User_full_org schJob = new Deactive_User_full_org(); 

        // Initialize some test data - BTW you may have trouble here because
        // of the fact that your Schedulable is messing with Setup objects (Users)
        // rather than records, so be careful about how you structure the test. You
        // can probably get away with it by "running" the Schedulable in Test.startTest/
        // Test.stopTest.

        // Now run the job. This passes in null as the context since the schedulable
        // doesn't use it at all
        Test.startTest();

        schJob.execute(null);

        Test.stopTest();

        // Now query data and apply asserts
    }
}
```

Comment: So i tried this and it just puts the test in 'que' and ...it just sits there in que in the apex test execution.

Comment: @ensir - that is indicative of a test execution still running; Phil's answer doesn't schedule a SFDC job, but running a test is a different kind of transaction. You need to abort prior test executions